# How to deal with NaN values in pandas (from csv file)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

I have a fairly large csv file filled with data obtained from a machine for material testing (compression test). The headers of the data are Time, Force, Stroke and they are repeated 10 times because of the sample size, so the last set of headers is Time.10, Force.10, Stroke.10.

Because of the nature of the experiment not all columns are equally long (some are approx.. 2000 rows longer than others). When I import the file into my IDE (spyder or jupyter) using pandas, all the cells within the the rows that are empty in the csv file are labeled as NaN.
The problem is... I can't do any mathematical operations within or between columns that have NaN values as they are treated as str. I have tried the most recommended solutions on pretty much all forums; .fillna(), dropna(), replace() and interpolate(). The mentioned methods work but only visually, e.g. df.fillna(0) replaces all NaN values with 0, but when I try to e.g. find the max value in the column, I still get the error that says that there are strings in my column (TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'). The problem is caused 100% by the NaN values that are the result of the empty cells in the csv file as I have imported a csv file in which all columns where the same length (with no empty cells) and there where no problems. If anyone has any solution to this problem  (doesn't need to be within pandas, just within Python) that I'm stuck on for over 2 weeks, I would be grateful.

Comment: The option `na_values` might be useful in pandas `read_csv` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: I think you may have something else going on in your data. The fact that `fillna()` works correctly means the values are actually `NaN` values, not the string `'nan'`, which is a `float()` type, and allows you to do math. Have you checked your other values for strings? `[i for i in df['column'] if isinstance(i,str)]`

Comment: @G.Anderson Yes, there are no strings in my file. The values are NaN, but the numeric values in my file are all decimal numbers. Is maybe that my issue, should does NaN's be transformed to nan's... e.g. 0.0 instead of replacing the NaN's with 0?

Comment: Solved! The solution that worked for me was: df.fillna(method="ffill"). I am not a pro (obviously) so I can't tell you why only this method worked, but it did.

Comment: @lignum Using 'ffill' just to fill empty cells would put false values in them, and it will ruin mathematical calculations on those columns

Comment: `NaN` is a float, it's clearly not the thing causing the `str` error. You have some underlying issue you should fix, instead of finding a solution that seems to work (though there's no reason it should). My guess is this will only cause headaches later.

Comment: *IF* you really have only numeric data, then you should do `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`. Either this will fix the few bad string values you have, or it will make everything `NaN` because they weren't recognizable numbers in the first place.

Comment: @ALollz Tried it, it turned all values to NaN, except zeros (0), zeros stayed zero.

Comment: Well my guess is that your numbers have commas in them. Probably read it in with `thousands=','` as a keyword. Numbers in python do not have these extraneous characters. One thousand is `1000` not `1,000`

Comment: @ALollz 1000 is  written as 1000.00, though e.g. 0,987 has a comma. Those decimal commas can't be the problem since I can do all math operations if I import the csv file without empty cells (the numbers are always the same).

Comment: @Aryerez You are right. The solution that finally worked is : df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) . It removed all the NaN's with empty strings that do not interfere with any operations.

Comment: Honestly I don’t know how you *import the data without empty cells*. I can almost guarantee that the empty string will cause issues. The decimal numbers with commas need to be fixed

Comment: Likely when you make them strings you just get string addition so that ‘1’ + ‘1’ gives ‘11’. You don’t want that. It might fix the error but only creates another problem.

Comment: @ALollz Do you have any idea how to fix those commas?

Answer (score 3):

Try *read_csv()* with *na_filter=False*.
This should at least prevent from setting "empty" source cells to *NaN*.

But note that:

- such "empty" cells can have an empty string as the content,
- the type of each column containing at least one such cell is *object*
  (not a number),
- so that (for the time being) they can't take part in any numeric
  operations.

So probably, after *read_csv()* you should:

- replace such empty strings with e.g. *0* (or whatever numeric value),
- call *to_numeric(...)* to change type of each column from *object*
  to whatever numeric type is appropriate in each case.